# Attempting to delete multiple rows from Pandas Dataframe but more rows than intended are being deleted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list, to_delete, of row indexes that I want to delete from both of my two Pandas Dataframes, df1 & df2. They both have 500 rows. to_delete has 50 entries.
I run this:

```
df1.drop(df1.index[to_delete], inplace=True)
df2.drop(df2.index[to_delete], inplace=True)
```

But this results in df1 and df2 having 250 rows each. It deletes 250 rows from each, and not the 50 specific rows that I want it to...

to_delete is ordered in descending order.

The full method:

```
def method(results):
    #results is a 500 x 1 matrix of 1's and -1s
    global df1, df2
    deletions = []
    for i in xrange(len(results)-1, -1, -1):
        if results[i] == -1:
        deletions.append(i)
    df1.drop(df1.index[deletions], inplace=True)
    df2.drop(df2.index[deletions], inplace=True)
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

(I've also tried using `.iloc` instead of `.index` and deleting in the `if statement` instead of appending to a list first.

Comment: If indexes of df are not unique (e.g. `data =pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], index=[1,1,2,3])`), then `data.drop(data.index[[1,2]], inplace=True)` will delete three rows, even-though you have passed only two indexes to drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index values are not unique and when you use `drop` it is removing all rows with those index values.  `to_delete` may have been of length 50 but there were 250 rows that had those particular index values.

Consider the example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(10)), [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] * 2)

df

   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
0  5
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9
```

---

Let's say you want to remove the first, third, and fourth rows.

```
to_del = [0, 2, 3]
```

Using your method

```
df.drop(df.index[to_del])

   A
1  1
4  4
1  6
4  9
```

Which is a problem

---

**Option 1**
use `np.in1d` to find complement of `to_del`
This is more self explanatory than the others.  I'm looking in an array from `0` to `n` and seeing if it is in `to_del`.  The result will be a boolean array the same length as `df`.  I use `~` to get the negation and use that to slice the dataframe.

```
df[~np.in1d(np.arange(len(df)), to_del)]

   A
1  1
4  4
0  5
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9
```

---

**Option 2**
use `np.bincount` to find complement of `to_del`
This accomplishes the same thing as option 1 by counting the positions defined in `to_del`.  I end up with an array of `0` and `1` with a `1` in each position defined in `to_del` and `0` else where.  I want to keep the `0`s so I make a boolean array by finding where it is equal to `0`.  I then use this to slice the dataframe.

```
df[np.bincount(to_del, minlength=len(df)) == 0]

   A
1  1
4  4
0  5
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9
```

---

**Option 3**
use `np.setdiff1d` to find positions
This uses set logic to find the difference between a full array of positions and just the ones I want to delete.  I then use `iloc` to select.

```
df.iloc[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(df)), to_del)]

   A
1  1
4  4
0  5
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions worked! Went with option 2, but I don't understand what it's actually doing. Could you please explain?
Also, just out of curiosity; I used pd.read_csv to get my dataframes, so how are the indexes not unique? I never set them to anything, I just assumed the index was basically just the row number? (Sorry, I'm new to Python (~3 weeks in)).

Comment: I've added some commentary.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @MahDhan in regards to the index unique-ness.  That is the only way I can imagine how your situation can happen.  When you read a csv, you can use part of the file as an index.  It may not be unique.  Also, when you ask questions.  We prefer it when you provide an example of what is causing you the problem.  That way, we remove ambiguity and make getting you what you need easier on everyone involved.